# T-SQL for Query that can be done in SQL. What do they want?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are given tables Vendors(VendorId, VendorName, ..) , Invoices(InvoiceId, VendorId...) 
I am going over a book exercise that asks for a T-SQL statement to find
all vendors with at least one invoice. But I am confused, since this can be perfectly done with standard SQL:

```
SELECT VendorName FROM Vendors V join Invoices I on V.VendorId=I.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorName having Count(InvoiceId) > = 1
```

So, what could they be asking? Should I come up with a procedure to select all vendors with more than n invoices; n= 0,1,2 ?

If so, why is this not working for the general case of n invoices:

```
 CREATE Procedure InvoiceCount @NumberofInvoices Int
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT VendorName FROM Vendors V join Invoices I on V.VendorId=I.VendorID
WHERE Count(InvoiceId) > = @Number of Invoices
EXEC InvoiceCount @Number of Invoices = n
```

Why doesn't this work?
  Thank you.

Comment: I believe your first query should be: `SELECT VendorName FROM Vendors V join Invoices I on V.VendorId=I.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorName HAVING Count(InvoiceId) > = 1`. But since the JOIN itself guarantees that there exists at least one invoice the `HAVING` clause is not necessary.

Comment: But MSSQL allows the use of having only if a 'Group By' is used. I tried to keep the query as short as possible.

Comment: Assuming `WHERE Count(InvoiceId) > = 1` works (which I don't think it should), you would still get duplicate VendorNames for those that have more than one invoice. So you need to either use distinct, or group by to get distinct VendorNames. Group by has the advantage that you can easily add an `HAVING` clause if you want to select vendors with more than n invoices, or whose invoice value exceeds a certain amount etc.

Comment: Good point, I was only thinking about n=1, where that would not matter.

Comment: I am unclear why we have moved on to a Stored Proc that returns vendors with more than N invoices if the requirement was "...a T-SQL statement to find all vendors with at least one invoice."

Comment: @ChadMattox: TL;DR: I was asked to write a T-SQL query to answer a question that seems to require only standard SQL. I am assuming this means the exercises  instead is about designing a general method for counting vendors with more than one invoice.

Comment: T-SQL is standard SQL on SQL Server.

Comment: The query is not valid SQL and not valid T-SQL either, as Lennart mentioned.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Yes, I get that.  I am wondering why the requirement has changed from a T-SQL Query that returns vendors with at least 1 invoice to a Stored Procedure that takes a parameter @N and returns vendors with greater than @N invoices.  That doesn't seem to be the question that was asked originally, "...a T-SQL statement to find all vendors with at least one invoice."

Comment: @ChadMattox: I answered that a few comments above.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ : Yes, I just remembered that you cannot use aggregates in 'where' clauses.

Comment: @MSIS - I don't think you did.  A T-SQL Query is a SQL Query.  The original question/requirement said nothing about a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the WHERE clause because you are doing an inner join, which ensures you will only get vendors that have an invoice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VendorName FROM Vendors V join Invoices I on V.VendorId=I.VendorID
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT VendorName 
FROM Vendors V 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invoices I WHERE V.VendorId=I.VendorID)
```

Answer (score 2):

what do you expect count to count?
you need to group by
and use having rather than where

```
SELECT VendorName 
FROM Vendors V 
join Invoices I on V.VendorId = I.VendorID 
group by VendorName 
having Count(*) >= @Number
```

Comment: But how do I return a value? EDIT Shouldn't this be a procedure that allows me to get a result for different values of @NumberofInvoices? Sorry, I am a beginner only.

Comment: But it does return a value - VendorName.  Exactly what you have in the current procedure.  What do you need?

Comment: I meant , can I get a procedure that will give me a result for different values of @Number of Invoices? Basically, if I wanted to know for, say, n=3 or n=4 . How would I get the VendorNames?

Comment: What makes you think this answer does not do that?  Have you tried it?

Comment: I get an error message asking me to declare NumberofInvoices .Sorry if I am obtuse, but I am trying to learn the syntax. Do I just write DECLARE @NumberofInvoices =3? Can only use an 'at' sign.

Comment: Ah, I see we use EXEC InvoiceCount @NumberofInvoices =3?

Comment: `DECLARE` requires a type. If you want 3, try `DECLARE @NumberofInvoices INT = 3` which will work if you are on SQL Server 2008 or higher. For earlier versions, `DECLARE @NumberofInvoices INT SET @NumberofInvoices = 3`

Answer (score 1):

If a question (in a Microsoft SQL Server specific context) asks for "a T-SQL statement to do X", then they are just asking for any SQL statement that would be valid on a SQL Server instance.

It does not have to use syntax that **only** works on SQL Server (but not MySQL etc). Standard ANSI SQL is fine if it works on SQL Server. (Not all ANSI SQL is valid on all SQL Server versions.)